# In C, how is modulus calculated for unsigned long?

Tags: c, math

In my function, I first use mod as below:

```
void function(int, int, unsigned int);
```

calling:

```
function(100, 200, get_value() % 1024);
```

The `get_value()` will return a unsigned int that varies from `0x`0 to `0xffffffff`. In this situation `get_value() % 1024` may be a very big number larger than `1024` that causes `function()` to run too many times, so I changed it as below:

```
unsigned int num = get_value() % 1024;
function(100, 200, num);
```

In this situation, `num` is ok. I used `gcc` to compile.

So what is the difference between these two methods and how does C calcuate modulus for `unsigned long`?

Comment: `get_value() % 1024` can never return a number larger than `1024`. It will be bounded by `[0, 1023]`. More generally, `a % b` will return a number in the range `[0, b - 1]`.

Comment: The problem is in code you haven't shown us. Can you write a small self-contained program that exhibits the problem? How do you know what the argument value is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prototype is for `function`, but you are calling `function1`. In this case, the `function1` function has no prototype, so the last parameter is considered to be an `int`. That's why you do not get the expected conversion.

Renaming the prototype should fix it:

```
void function1(int, int, unsigned int);
```

Comment: this is a mistaken that i post it while i used it right in my app

Comment: @Ezio I tried this on [ideone](http://ideone.com/xRic7), and I get good results when `get_value()` is declared as returning `unsigned int`. I also get an error when `get_value` is declared as returning `int`. You can work around this by replacing `%` with an equivalent `get_value() & 0x3FF` for unsigned values.

Comment: thanks,your idea could work but i'm not sure about how C calcuates modulus.

Comment: @Ezio It calculates the remainder the same way you do in math - the number `R` that needs to be added to the result of integer division `A/B` multiplied by `B` so that the result `(A/B)*B+R = A`. When `A` is negative and `B` does not divide `A`, `R` will be negative too. Negative numbers in two's complement become large positive numbers, causing the problem that you see.